# Using Pytest, can I find out which tests execute a single line of code?

Tags: python, pytest, code-coverage

I am using pytest to run my Python tests. Is there a way I can run  I'd like to know which tests cover a specific line of code. I want to be able to run just the tests that execute a specific line. I know the `coverage` tool collects related data, but I feel this use case is not covered.

Comment: A simple answer is to raise an exception in the test suite at that specific line, and list the failing tests, but I'd prefer a less brute force approach!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coverage.py can annotate source lines with the names of all the tests that ran that line: https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/7.2.3/contexts.html#dynamic-contexts

I'm interested to hear ideas about what I could do to make this easier to find.

Comment: That's fantastic, thanks Ned, and thank you for creating coverage.py!